# Is it possible to get iOS Remote Notifications from Twitter in own App?

Tags: ios, twitter, push-notification

I'm working on a special purpose iPhone twitter client. The client will show only messages from some internet of things devices.

Up to now, I used background fetch to get the tweets, but found it too unreliable, as the app will be shut down depending on how the user uses his phone.

Silent remote notifications seem to be a solution, as they can reactivate the app in such cases.

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out if and how it is possible to register an self written twitter client for twitter push notifications. The twitter developer page just mentions the Rest and streaming APIs and such, but no notifications. Searching for push or notifications in their site search delivers hardly any results. On the other hand, the original twitter client has push notifications settings for several event categories.

As wikipedia says, there are 750.000 developers worldwide working on twitter clients, maybe you are one of them and can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, just some hours after posting the question, I found some hints that I won't find my desired solution. Here's another thread pointing this out:
[Twitter New tweets feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068626/twitter-new-tweets-feature)